# Laravel no publica el metodo POST

Tags: laravel, post

quisiera su ayuda en un error que estoy recibiendo, espero su ayuda!.

Ese error aparece al apretar el botón "Guardar", cuando realizo alguna modificación de un registro (El formulario de editar es un Modal), espero que alguien me pueda ayudar!, les envió el código y el error que me aparece, al igual que las rutas que tengo las cuales son las que crea laravel.
me devuelve este error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**EDIT.BLADE.PHP**

```
<div class="table-container">
  <form method="POST" action="{{ route('asistencia.update',$asist->id) }}"  role="form">
              {{ csrf_field() }}

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Rut</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="EJ.: 12345678-9" name="rut_alumno" value="{{$asist->rut_alumno}}">
    </div>

    <div class='input-group date' id='fechaAsistencia'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresar Fecha" name="fecha_asistencia" value="{{$asist->fecha_asistencia}}"/>
     <span class="input-group-addon">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
     </span>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
        <label>Asistencia</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="listadoEstadoAsistencia" name="id_estado"  value="{{$asist->id_estado}}">
        @foreach ($listEstado_Asistencia as $listadoEA)
        <option value="{{ $listadoEA['id_estado'] }}">{{$listadoEA['nombre'] }}</option>
        @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Curso</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="listadoCursos" name="id_curso" value="{{$asist->id_curso}}">
        @foreach ($listCursosA as $listadoC)
        <option value="{{ $listadoC['id'] }}">{{$listadoC['nombre'] }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <input type="submit"  value="Actualizar" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
        <a href="{{ route('alumnos.index') }}" class="btn btn-info btn-block" >Atrás</a>
     </div>  
     </div>
     </form>
     </div>
```

**ASISTENCIACONTROLLER**

```
public function edit($id)
{

    $listCursosA = Curso::all();
    $listEstado_Asistencia = Estado_asistencia::all();
    $asist=Asistencia::find($id);
    return view('asistencia.edit')
    ->with(compact('asist'))
    ->with(compact('listCursosA'))
    ->with(compact('listEstado_Asistencia'));
}
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    Asistencia::find($id)->update($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('asistencia.index')->with('success','Registro actualizado satisfactoriamente');
}
```

ROUTES
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estas enviando un POST a una ruta definida como PUT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dentro de tu form después de la directiva `csrf`, declara ahora una directiva de este modo:

```
  @method("PUT")
```

Para reconocer el verbo HTTP que será usado, ya que si observas en tu listado usa `PUT`

Referencia: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#form-method-spoofing

Comment: al hacer eso me aparece un nuevo error y no me muestra el modal, el error es:

Comment: jquery.min.js:2 GET http://localhost:8000/asistencia/8/edit 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: En cuanto tenga acceso a una PC te respondo

Comment: Gracias Compañero

Comment: Revisa el log de errores para ver exactamente que es lo que esta ocurriendo

Comment: ya arregle el error añadiendo lo que mecomentaste pero ademas, agrgegando assents en mis css, nose por que, pero me lo soluciono

Answer (score 0):

mira, yo tengo esto funcionando por si te puede servir:
Las rutas:

```
 Route::get('event/edit/{eventoId}', [
    'as'=>'evento-editar', 
    'uses'=>'EventoController@getEditEvent'
])->middleware('auth');

Route::post('event/update/{eventoId}', [
    'as'=>'evento-actualizar', 
    'uses'=>'EventoController@putUpdateEvent'
])->middleware('auth');
```

Las funciones del controlador:

```
public function getEditEvent($eventoId)
{
    $evento = Evento::where('id', $eventoId)->first();

    if (Auth::user() != $evento->user)
    {
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    $data = array('evento' => $evento);
    return view('eventos.editar', $data);
}


public function putUpdateEvent($eventoId, Request $request)
{
    $evento = Evento::findOrFail($eventoId);


    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required|max:140',
        'date' => 'required|max:14',
        'hour_start' => 'required|date_format:"H:i"',

    ]);

    $evento->title = $request['title'];
    $evento->date = $request['date'];
    $evento->hour_start = $request['hour_start'];
    $request->user()->evento()->save($evento);      

    return redirect('/dashboard')->with(['message' => 'Event successfully modified']);
}
```

y el formulario en la vista:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{URL::route('evento-actualizar', $evento->id)}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {!! csrf_field() !!}
```

Comment: No amigo :c el mimso error

Comment: puedes adaptar tu respuesta al codigo del usuario?

Comment: Este código no sirve para nada, no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta.